# smb file writing in local drive from network drive is not working

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, smb, file-writing

I am trying to write a file in my local drive which is available in a network drive on a server. I can write this image and I can see even the size of the file available. But, when I'm opening the file it says preview not available. Content of the file is not coming.

Code which I read the network file

```
SmbFileInputStream sfis = null;
sfis = new SmbFileInputStream(serverFile);
fileBytes = new byte[(int) serverFile.length()];
sfis.read(fileBytes);
```

Code which I write the file in my local drive

```
FileOutputStream fos;
fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(fileBytes);
```

I also tried with file.copyTo method by giving my local file like a smbfile.

```
serverFile.copyTo(ss);
```

Comment: It's possible that you're not closing or flushing the file

Comment: actually I have them in my code which is not copied here. I have flush and close for writing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it works fine.

Change first two lines to

```
InputStream sfis = new SmbFileInputStream(serverFile);
```

real change is reference of the variable is now

```
InputStream
```